# How do I fix check in failing for TFVC extension in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, visual-studio-2017, azure-devops, tfvc

I have an Angular 6 application I am developing in using Visual Studio, but my repository is on a Team Foundation Server using TFVC.  I installed the **Visual Studio Team Services** extension ([ms-vsts.team](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vsts.team)).  I have the latest version of the extension (v1.136.0) as of 7/8/2018, and the latest version of Visual Studio Code (1.25.0) as of 7/8/2018, and I have **Visual Studio 2017 Professional** with Team Foundation installed and verified that I have TF.exe installed in the location the official docs say it should be.  I can successfully connect to my repository with credentials, but each time I attempt to check in changes, I get the following error:

```
tf checkin -noprompt ******** C:\Apps\my-app\README.md -comment:updated readme
[Checkin] Execution of the TFVC command line failed unexpectedly.
```

Has anyone encountered this before?  I am just trying to do a simple check in but it fails for me every time -- to this day I have not successfully checked in changes through VSCode...I can check in changes through Visual Studio, just not VSCode.

Comment: Can you show related screen shots for the VSCode when the error message occur? And does the TFVC repo show connected in the left-bottom of the VSCode (as the example shows https://ibb.co/gprnsT)?

Comment: @MarinaLiu-MSFT, yes, it does show as connected via the icons in the lower left corner.  There really isn't anything to show in terms of screenshots other than the output window, which says basically what I included in the questions.

Comment: Have you configured `tfvc.location` for the settings file?

Comment: @MarinaLiu-MSFT Yep, configured it to the correct location of my TF.exe.  Still no good.  It appears the problem is that my TF instance requires me to link my check in to a work item, but that also fails.  I can override the work item requirement, but that in turn requires a prompt to be displayed which apparently Visual Studio Code cannot handle.

Comment: TF won't restrick to link work item when checkin changes. And please make sure the `tfvc.location` has \\ instead of \. Such as `"tfvc.location": "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\Community\\Common7\\IDE\\CommonExtensions\\Microsoft\\TeamFoundation\\Team Explorer\\TF.exe"`.

Comment: @MarinaLiu-MSFT the TF location has the double back slash and still no good

Comment: There has an issue https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-vscode/issues/393 for the same problem there. You can also follow up there.

Comment: Is there any special character in the file path?

Comment: @EddieChen-MSFT, none that I could see.  The file path was correct and pointed to the correction location of the exe on my machine.  Almost seems like a bug with the extension.

Comment: @j-man: I encounter the same issue. Were you able to solve it? The same issue is indeed described on github: https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-vscode/issues/393, however no usefull solution is proposed.

Answer (score -1):

Like I commented in question above. I encountered the same issue.
Now I was able to resolve it.

> The problems was caused, by files that were included as changes, but
>   no longer existed on the disk.

How could that happen?

> During development I added a component and later I
>   removed it. At the end of my task, I checked in the code and then the
>   error occured. It seems that for some reason(**), when doing a
>   deletion of the component, it didn't removed "the definition as
>   changed file" into tfs. When I manualy delete this change I was
>   able to check in the code.

(**) Concerning the reason why this happend: added and deleted files are added to list of "excluded changes". So when you have a lot of added files/deleted file, the easist way to include them quickly is to include them all in one click. But then offcourse we added the changes of the component that no longer exist and the problem occured.

Comment: I am also facing the same problem and this is due to implemented TFS checkin policies, if I removed custom checkin policies from TFS, than I am able to checkin my code from Visual Studio Code, again if I apply checkin policies i.e 'checkin comments' it works fine in VS Code, and if applied 2nd policy 'associate WI' than not able to checkin through VS code? still finding the solution